# AZURE: upload attachment over az board workitem

Tags: azure, azure-rest-api

I've a question, I automate so many tasks using the CLI tool

```
az boards work-item relation show
az boards work-item show
az boards work-item update
```

But now, my doubt is, as part of my automation, I need to upload an attachment to some workitems, is possible do that using the CLI?

Searching I found this link:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/attachments/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#upload-a-text-file
```

But I do not see where specify the workitem ID where you want to upload the file, somebody face by this need?

Thank you, best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I do not see where specify the work item ID where you want to upload the file, somebody face by this need?

*Yes, you can upload the attachment in a specific work item in two steps-*

**First Create the attachment file using below URL**

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/attachments?fileName=textAsFileAttachment.txt&api-version=7.0
```

Here Request Body is `"User text content to upload"`

[image]

**Second add this attachment to a specific work item using below URL**

```
PATCH https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=5.0
```

*Request Body-*

Use the above generated URL in below request body

```
[
{
"op": "add",
"path": "/relations/-",
"value": {
"rel": "AttachedFile",
"url": "https://dev.azure.com/{collection}/yyyyyyyy/_apis/wit/attachments/xxxxxxxxxxx?fileName=textAsFileAttachment.txt",
"attributes": {
"comment": "Spec for the work"
}
}
}
]
```

[image]

[image]

*In this way, you can upload an attachment to a work item*.

*You can refer to this [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66101212/ado-upload-an-attachment-to-azure-devops-via-http-rest-request)  and [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0&tabs=HTTP#add-an-attachment) as well*.

Answer (score 0):

I reply to myself, it was fixed, my problem was in the "Content-Type", as the documentation, when upload, should be use "application/octet-stream" instead "application/json"

Thanks again :-)